# How to plot longitudinal data / repeated measures in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

How do I plot longitudinal data in python using, e.g., matplotlib.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# some sample data
df = DataFrame({
    'one' : norm.rvs(loc=12, size=10),
    'two' : norm.rvs(loc=5, size=10),
    'three' : norm.rvs(loc=7, size=10),
    'four' : norm.rvs(loc=3, size=10),
    'type' : ['type-%i' % i for i in randint.rvs(0,3,size=10)]})
```

How can I plot on the x-axis the labels of the repeated measures: one-two-three-four, and for each of the 10 samples a line connecting their respective values? How can I colour each sample by its type?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the part of the connecting line, but perhaps this what you want is something similar to this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1, 1 )

ax.plot( np.zeros(len(df.one))+1, df.one, '.' )
ax.plot( np.zeros(len(df.two)) + 2, df.two, '.' )
ax.plot( np.zeros(len(df.three)) + 3 , df.three, '.' )
ax.plot( np.zeros(len(df.four)) + 4, df.four, '.' )

ax.set_xticks([1,2,3,4]);
ax.set_xticklabels(( 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ))
ax.set_xlim([0,5]);
```

Which results on:

[image]